# define a function that returns a nxn square matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am just learning python and want to define a function that returns a nxn square matrix, with predefined values for the main diagonal(i=j), upper diagonal (j=i+1)and lower diagonal (j=i-1) and all other elements to be equal 0.

Any help would be appreciated,

thanks

---

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy as sp 
n=6 
m=np.zeros((n,n)) 
for i in range(n): 
    m[i-1,i]=-1 
    m[i,i]=2 
    m[i,i-1]=1 
    m[0,n-1]=0 
    m[n-1,0]=0 
print m
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


n=6

m=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    m[i-1,i]=-1
    m[i,i]=2
    m[i,i-1]=1
    m[0,n-1]=0
    m[n-1,0]=0

print m

Comment: I moved your code to the question.  It formats better there.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has a couple of ways of setting multiple diagonals at once.  The `numpy.diag` sets one diagonal at a time, but otherwise is easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that takes in a list of items to add on the diagonal, using [`numpy.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) and taking advantage of the `k` parameter to specify which diagonal we want to modify.

```
import numpy as np

def create_diag(n, l):
    arr = np.zeros((n, n))

    # check that l contains an odd number of elements
    if len(l) % 2 != 1:
        return arr

    # check that we have at most the number of diagonals in the matrix
    if len(l) >= 2*n:
        return arr

    # set limits of diagonals to set. setting 3 diagonals means limits=[-1,0,1]. setting 1 diagonal means limits=[0]
    limit = int((len(l) - 1) / 2)
    limits = range(-limit, limit + 1)

    # maps k-->list of values on the diagonal
    diag_map = dict(zip(limits, l))
    for k, v in diag_map.items():
        diag = [v] * (n - abs(k))
        arr += np.diag(diag, k=k)
    return arr

# elements to put on the diagonal, centered about the main diagonal (i=j)
l = [-1,1,2]
n = 6

diag_arr = create_diag(n, l)

# [[ 1.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [-1.  1.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0. -1.  1.  2.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0. -1.  1.  2.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0. -1.  1.  2.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `a,b,c` are your three list for the upper diagonal, main diagonal, and lower diagonal respectively, you can write it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,6,7,8,9]
c=[10,11,12,13]
n=len(b)
m=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(0,n-1):
    m[i,i+1]=a[i]
    m[i,i]=b[i]
    m[i+1,i]=c[i]
m[n-1,n-1]=b[n-1]
print(m)
```

In the code above you initialize a zero matrix, and then update only the upper,lower, and main diagonal entries according to your lists.
The output is

```
[[  5.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 10.   6.   2.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  11.   7.   3.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  12.   8.   4.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  13.   9.]]
```

Edit: A shorter way, suggested by @hpaulj would be

```
m=np.diag(a,1)+np.diag(b,0)+np.diag(c,-1)
```

`np.diag(r,k)` create a matrix in which the `k`'th diagonal above the main diagonal (below if `k` is negative) is `r` and the rest of the entries are 0.

See documentation here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html

Comment: Play with `np.diag(a,1)+np.diag(b,0)+np.diag(c,-1)`

Comment: @hpaulj nice trick.. But, I guess this only works fine if the off-diagonal elements are zeros